# How to add this array without adding columns again in the array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to remove this code and set to default values in the table

> model2.setColumnIdentifiers(new
>   Object[]{"Order_ID","Description","Quantity","Amount","Order_Time","Cost"});

```
public void finduserday(){

         ArrayList<dayday> list = userlistdaysearch (((JTextField)jDateChooser_searchdate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
         DefaultTableModel model2 = new DefaultTableModel();
         model2.setColumnIdentifiers(new Object[]{"Order_ID","Description","Quantity","Amount","Order_Time","Cost"});
         Object [] row= new Object[6];
         for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){

             row[0]=list.get(i).getOrder_ID();
             row[1]=list.get(i).getDescription();
             row[2]=list.get(i).getQuantity();
             row[3]=list.get(i).getAmount();
             row[4]=list.get(i).getOrder_Time();
              row[5]=list.get(i).getCost();
             model2.addRow(row);
         }
         jTable_dayday.setModel(model2);

}
```

Comment: You should describe your problem a little more.

Comment: Do you want to set DEFAULT VALUES in a row in THE TABLE with 'Order_ID,....' columns? e.g ::  "1, sample product, 10, 1299" ?